# How to keep thread on processor till an event happens?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, kernel

I am spawning few threads inside ioctl call to my driver. I am also assigning kernel affinity to my driver. I want to ensure one of the thread does not get scheduled out till a particular event is flagged by the other thread. Is there any way to not allow windows scheduler to context out my thread. Using _disable() may hang the system as event may take couple of seconds.

Environment is windows 7,64bit

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably after is a spin lock. However this is probably a bad idea unless you can guarantee that your driver/application is always run on a multi-processor system, even then it is still very bad practice. On a single processor system if a thread spin locks then the other thread signalling the spin locked thread will never be scheduled and so can't signal your event. Spin locks are meant to be used sparingly and only when the lock is for a very short time, never a couple of seconds.
It sounds like you need to use an event or other signally mechanism to synchronise your threads and let the windows scheduler do its job. If you need to respond to an event very quickly then interrupts or a Deferred Procedure Call (DPC) could be used instead.